# How do you make a button disabled at first when the page is rendered and then it will be enabled when 2 button is pressed

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make the third button `graph` disabled at first and after the first 2 buttons (button1 and button2) is pressed and hidden, third will be enabled and can click on it.

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="button1" onclick="dataButton1(); this.style.visibility= 'hidden'; this.disabled=true">Data1</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="button2" onclick="dataButton2();this.style.visibility= 'hidden'; this.disabled=true">data2</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary " id="button3" onclick="chart1();this.style.visibility= 'hidden'; this.disabled=true">Graph</button>
```

Comment: 1. Missing a quote. 2. IDs need to be unique. 3. Where is the attempt?

Comment: You should try to understand basics of manipulating DOM elements usin JavaScript, there's tons of great resources out there. Put more effort into trying out the possible solutions. Google before you post a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a go with this

```js
const dataButton1 = () => console.log("1")
const dataButton2 = () => console.log("2")
const chart1 = () => console.log("chart 1")

const container = document.getElementById("container");
const buttons = [...container.querySelectorAll("button")]; 

container.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.id === "button1") {
    dataButton1();
  }  
  else if (tgt.id === "button2") {
    dataButton2();
  }  
  else if (tgt.id === "button3") {
    chart1();
  }  
  tgt.setAttribute("hidden",true); // hide
  
  const show = buttons.map(btn => btn.getAttribute("hidden")); // cannot use hasAttribute here
  if (show[0] && show[1] && !show[2]) buttons[2].removeAttribute("disabled");
  

})
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="button1">Data1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="button2">Data2</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="button3" disabled>chart</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First add `disable` attribute to third button. Then on each click of button 1 and 2 check for `hasAttribute("disabled")` of other button to see both of them are clicked (and disabled) or not

Here is working sample:

```js
   function dataButton1() {
            if (document.getElementById("button2").hasAttribute("disabled"))
                document.getElementById("button3").setAttribute("disabled", false);
        }
        function dataButton2() {
            if (document.getElementById("button1").hasAttribute("disabled"))
                document.getElementById("button3").removeAttribute("disabled");
        }
```

```html
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="button1"
            onclick="dataButton1(); this.style.visibility='hidden'; this.disabled=true">
        Data1
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="button2"
            onclick="dataButton2();this.style.visibility= 'hidden'; this.disabled=true">
        data2
    </button>
    <button disabled type="button" class="btn btn-primary " id="button3">
        chart
    </button>
```

Comment: the button3 was not enabled after button 1 and 2 is pressed?

Comment: @hello9394 No it enables after clicking on button 1 and 2. button 3 is `chart` button that enables after clicking button 1 and clicking button 2

Comment: it did not enable when i use this code? the 3rd button stayed as disabled

Comment: I made a snippet for you, you can run it and see what happened. Now I run it and everything is working here

Comment: Note that I edit html too, your html has some problem such as same id and so on. please check my html too in your code